# sub-menu expansion and innerHTML replacement based on onclick, using just Javascript

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick, html-lists, innerhtml

First, I should mention that I'm about 4-weeks new to the coding world, and this is the first time I'm trying to make (what I thought would be) a simple site.

I have seen many similar questions on Stack Overflow, but in trying to adapt the code samples provided in the solutions, the solution would stop working.

So, the current hurdle is:

- I have a menu defined in HTML with a sub-menu in one of the `<li>` elements ("Portfolio"), and that `<li>` element contains the character ▼ (&#9660).
- I set up an `onclick` event for that `<li>` element so that when it was clicked it would do two things: expand/display the sub-menu `<li>` elements directly below it (pushing the other `<li>` elements in the menu further down), and replace the ▼ character with a ▲ character (&#9650)... until the `<li>` element was clicked again to shrink/hide the sub-menu.
- I'm not sure if it matters, but this menu is inside a grid item because the page is set up using CSS Grid.

So basically:

- HOME
- ABOUT US
- PORTFOLIO ▼
- INFORMATION
- CONTACT

...would become:

- HOME
- ABOUT US
- PORTFOLIO ▲

  - LINK 1
  - LINK 2
  - LINK 3
- INFORMATION
- CONTACT

No matter how I set up my classes and IDs, I cannot get the arrow symbol to swap, and somewhere along the line, I messed up the coding and now the sub-menu doesn't even expand anymore.

It's likely embarrassingly bad code (given that I've tried to mash together bits from samples I've seen) but here is what I have. Thanks in advance.

```js
       var arrowstring = document.getElementById("arrowdirection").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("IDforPortfolioLink").classList.toggle("show");
        if (IDforPortfolioLink.classList.contains('show')) {
          arrowstring = "&#9650"
        } else {
          arrowstring = "&#9660"
        }
        arrowdirection.textContent = arrowstring;
      }
```

```css
.sub-menu-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
  }
.sub-menu-content a {
 display: block;
}
.sub-menu-content a:hover {
 background-color: green;
   }
.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
    
    
      <body>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li class="LinkForPortfolio" id="IDforPortfolioLink" onclick= "myFunction()"><a href="#">LINK <span class="arrow" id= "arrowdirection">&#9660;</span></a><div class="sub-menu-content" id="myportfolio">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code had so many flaws I had to rewrite it. 
I'll explain everything that I possibly can of what I did here:

1. I changed the HTML a bit: I have added div's, instead of ul's with li's, inside a nav(container). It's more indicated to do so because it keeps the markup clean, and is less harder to debug.
2. I have assigned `nav` a `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` which centers the divs inside `nav`, and inlines them. I did so with `nav div`, which pretty much centered the text inside of them.
3. I have removed all of the classes expect of `.portfolio` because it's useless to have that many classes.
4. I made `div.expand-portfolio` a child of `div.portfolio`, which in itself(.expand-portfolio) has another `ul` child, which holds the links. You might've noticed that I've added `.portfolio` a `position: relative;` and `.expand-portfolio` a `position: absolute;`. I did that because, I wanted to take `.expand-portfolio` out of the document flow, which basically means I wanted to make `.expand-portfolio` not interact with any element on the page. Now, when assigning `position: absolute;` to a child inside a container, the child's position is going to be relative to the *document* and not the  parent. This is why you may add `position: relative;` to the parent.
5. I created a separate class called `.expanded` which gives `.expand-portfolio` a height of 150px when assigned to it.

You also might have noticed I gave the `div`s inside the `nav` a `transition: 500ms ease`, what that does is make the transition between the properties smooth, and not sudden. You may remove that property from them if you don't want that.

Now, the javascript.

1. When I made those 3 variables, which are the references of the elements from the page, you noticed I used `document.getElementsByClassName` followed by a `[0]`. What `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns is: a *nodelist*. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). It's basically a sort of "array", and with [0] appended to it, I select only the first and only element of the page with that class.
2. You may have observed I added the `onclick` function in the javascript file. Personal preference. I said that when I click the portfolio button, first, you should change that span's `innerHTML`. (the span element holds the actual symbol). I also said you should toggle the `.expanded` class. And, I made an if statement, checking if `.expand-portfolio` *doesn't* contain the class. If it doesn't, you can pretty much see what it does.

I hope it helps. If you have any more questions, ask them in the comments.

```js
var portfolio = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio")[0];
var portfolioInner = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-html")[0];
var expandPortfolio = document.getElementsByClassName("expand-portfolio")[0];

portfolio.onclick = function(){
   portfolioInner.innerHTML = "▲";
   expandPortfolio.classList.toggle("expanded");
   if(!expandPortfolio.classList.contains("expanded")){
    portfolioInner.innerHTML = "▼"
   }
};
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.menus-container {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
}

.menus-container > div  {
padding: 10px 10px 5px;
transition: 500ms ease;
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
}

.expand-portfolio {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px;
height: 0; 
background-color: #000;
transition: 500ms ease;
}

.expand-portfolio ul {
 padding-left: 25px;
}

.expand-portfolio ul li {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.portfolio span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.expanded {
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
    
    
      <body>
      <div class="menus-container">
       <div>Home</div>
       <div>About Us</div>
       <div class="portfolio">Portfolio <span class="inner-html">&#9660</span>
        <div class="expand-portfolio">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div>Information</div>
       <div>Contact</div>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi MWR. Thank you very much for your solution and the detailed explanation. It will go further towards my understanding how things fit together.
Is there any chance, just for simplicity, that you could reduce the coding to its absolute minimum, and at the same time, keep the menu as a simple, **vertical** menu rather than as part of a horizontal drop-down? 
Thank you again.

Comment: More like this? Check the snippet again.

Comment: That is indeed the menu style that I need!  Thank you!!  Would I be able to change the individual LI elements in the sub-menu into links just by again encompassing them in <a href="#...."></a> ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I've nested `<a>`s in the `<li>`s. Check the snippet again if you want.

Comment: Thanks again, MWR.  Not sure why the pointer doesn't change when it moves between the links, but I think I won't worry about that now.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to vote up your answer, but it's telling me that I need a higher "reputation".

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I'm happy it helped you anyways.

Comment: A note on the innerHTML property: Using this can screw up the document if not done carefully (in fact, one can introduce arbitrary HTML code this way, even to the extent that entirely invalid code can be inserted), and it also isn't portable. Should you decide to move to XHTML, this property is read-only so that this approach is going to fail.

Better use innerText instead (this can be written to), or better yet, childNodes[0].data (you may have to browse the DOM tree to find the correct index of the text in question). Both can be written to and cannot be used to insert any markup.